# Show count of invitations sent

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, buddypress

I have a function which sends private message of the of the current event for invitation, which is a CPT. Now i want to show the total count of invitations sent. I'm using BuddyPress btw. Here is the code:

```
function invite_friend_to_event(){
    $message = 'Check out this event! <br><a href="'.$_POST['event_url'].'">'.$_POST['event_title'].'</a>';
    $msg_args = array(
    'sender_id' => get_current_user_id(), // 1 = admin
    'recipients' => $_POST["user_id"],
    'subject' => 'Event invitation!',
    'content' => $message
    );
    $thread_id = messages_new_message($msg_args);

    echo "Invitation sent!";
    die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_invite_friend', 'invite_friend_to_event');
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_invite_friend', 'invite_friend_to_event' );
```

And my frontend template:

```
<div class="event invite-friends">

    <script>
        function invite_friends(userid){
            jQuery.ajax({
                url:"<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>",
                type:'POST',
                data: {
                    action : 'invite_friend',
                    user_id : userid,
                    event_url : '<?php the_permalink();?>',
                    event_title : '<?php echo $event->get_title(); ?>'
                },
                dataType : 'html',
                success:function(results)
                {
                    alert(results);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
    <h4 class="small">Invite Friends</h4>
    <?php
        $uid = get_current_user_id();
        $friends_list = friends_get_friend_user_ids( $uid, false, true );
        foreach($friends_list as $friend):
            $friend_obj = get_userdata($friend['user_id']);
        ?>
        <div class="invitee">
                <span class="small"><?php echo $friend_obj->first_name." ".$friend_obj->last_name; ?></span>
                <?php echo get_avatar( $friend['user_id'], 64 ); ?>
                <button class='btn-success btn' onclick="invite_friends('<?php echo $friend['user_id']; ?>');">
                <span class='small white'>Invite</span></button>
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing an ajax post to `admin-ajax.php` then that script (apart from what it's doing at the moment i.e. sending the invitation) could increment a counter in a database somewhere.

If you wanted to use the new incremented count after each invite then just return it as part of the ajax response and then show on the page somewhere. If you do not care for that then you can just fetch the invite count from the database on the next reload of a php page.